# bootsrap center elements alignments when the screen size changes

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, grid

I'm a beginner in bootstrap and trying to build a web app using it. I want to have two text boxes on the center of the browser and only the larger display must have those textboxes in-line.  If I do a "pull-right" and "pull-left" on them it is giving me my expected behavior on medium to larger devices. But for small devices on i want them on 2 separated rows and have them on the center of the window. But because of the pulls, on smaller screen sizes alignments doesn't happen as I wanted.

This is my code:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <input type="text" value="1"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                        <input type="text" value="1"/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Expected on smaller devices:

```
  |                             |-------------|                         |                         
  |                             |   text box1 |                         |
  |                             |-------------|                         |
  |                             |-------------|                         |        
  |                             |   text box2 |                         |
  |                             |-------------|                         |
```

Current behavior on smaller devices:

```
  |   |-------------|                                 |-------------|   |                         
  |   |   text box1 |                                 |  text box2  |   |
  |   |-------------|                                 |-------------|   |              |
```

Comment: pull-right and pull-left are for all viewport widths. You need to roll your own for min-width 992px, such as pull-right-md {} inside the media query for that break point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" value="1" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 col-md-2 col-md-push-8  col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <input type="text" value="1" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Overview:**

I basically removed the `pull-left` and `pull-right` classes to avoid any problems that may occur in the future. With that being said, I added `col-sm-12` and `col-xs-12` to symbolize that when the device is a small/extra-small screen, the content should take up all 12 columns of the row, pushing anything else to the next line.

I also set an appropriate length for your text box inputs, but you can always adjust that as needed - 2 seemed like a fair number. The below example will give you a better feel for what you want to accomplish. You can move the screen size of the bottom right screen to adjust it from large - extra small screens.

### **[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kN2p3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using pull-right to move it to the center, have you considered using column offsets?

For example, if you use `col-md-offset-4`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-2">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="1"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="1"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```